# Recusively Enumerable or Recursive dependent on whether P=NP

Tags: computability, regular-languages, p-vs-np

If a language is defined such that
$L = (0+1)^{\ast}$   if $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$ and $\emptyset$   otherwise

Then $L$ is a regular language if $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$, otherwise it is the empty langauge. 
Therefore $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$ , $L$ is recursive (being regular), but is $L$ still recursive if $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$?

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. We have migrated your question to [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Comment: In both cases L is regular ans thus recursive.

Comment: @Ran G. Turn into an answer?

Answer (score 7):

The language $L = \emptyset$  is indeed a recursive set.